# Redux-saga: How to type worker's parameter with typeScript

Tags: typescript, redux-saga, worker

Is there any way to use typescript to set the parameter type on worker saga?

I have this interface

```
interface ITask{
    id: number
    task: string,
    //other things here
}
```

And i have this listener and worker:

```
function* addTaskSaga():any {
    yield takeEvery("TASK_ADD", workerAddTaskSaga);
}
function* workerAddTaskSaga({data}:any) {
  //other things here
}
```

This code is working well, however I want to strong type the parameter of the worker, I mean: change `{data}:any` to `data:ITask`

However this throws an exception:

```
The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>'.ts(2769)
effects.d.ts(207, 17): The last overload is declared here.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If question is still relevant here is the answer.

You shuold define some interface which extends `Action` from redux and then pass it as type argument to `takeEvery`. This will properly type worker function.

```
// This is Action interface which will hold type and payload. 
interface TaskAction extends Action, ITask {type: "TASK_ADD" }

// Alternatively you may use 
// interface TaskAction extends Action {type: "TASK_ADD", data: ITask }

interface ITask{
  id: number
  task: string,
  //other things here
}

function* addTaskSaga():any {
  yield takeEvery<TaskAction>("TASK_ADD", workerAddTaskSaga);
}

function* workerAddTaskSaga(data:TaskAction) {
  // data is of type TaskAction
  // data.id is number from ITask
  // data.task is string from ITask
}

// Or if you've chosen second form of TaskAction
//   function* workerAddTaskSaga({ data } : TaskAction) {
     // data is of type ITask
//   }
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure that the first argument passed to `takeEvery` matches the type parameter given. `"TASK_ADD"` may as well be `"asdasdasdasfsdfdfs"` (causing the worker saga to never be invoked).

Comment: May I ask, what exactly is ```Action```? For example ```PayloadAction``` in Redux toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

in my case

```
import {  PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
...

function* applyFilterRun(action: PayloadAction<IProcedureFilterParams>) {
    yield put(setFilter(action.payload)); 
}
```